# Clone SQL Server Database without using a backup

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to create a copy of one database with data but not using a backup file?

I tried DBCC CLONEDATABASE but is not copying the data. I'm using SQL Server 2014

I want to do it using an script without using any wizard.

Comment: Redgate offer a cloning tool, but there's nothing out of the box that does this: https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-clone/

Comment: You can simply copy the mdf and ldf files. To do so, you need to detach the database, copy the files, and attach the database back. It's pretty simple and easy to do.

Comment: thanks to all for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
1) Create your Database. 
2) Generate the Schema Scripts of the Source Database
   2.1) Right Click your source DatabseName > Generate Scripts.
   2.2) Select "Script specific database objects", Select all Checked-boxes
   2.3) Select "Save to new query window"
   2.4) You will now see the scripts to create all the schemas, Where it say USE 
        [DatabseName] change that to your new Database.
3) Now for the Data, you do the same above but with a few changes. 
   You could do the data and Schema together, but I prefer to do it individually,
   especially if you have large databases.   
3.1) Right Click your source DatabseName > Generate Scripts. 
3.2) Click on "Advanced"
3.3) Scroll down to "Types of data to script" and select "Data Only"
3.4) Select "Save to new query window"
3.5) You see all the data in a SQL script, again change the "USE [DatabseName]" 
     to your new Database.
```